# How do we push all files using adb push?

Tags: android, adb

Like in Mac/Linux, we have `adb push *` (using wildcard method) command to push all files inside the folder similarly whats the command for same function in windows system?

Comment: adb push C:\directory\. /data/ (worked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried pushing the contents of a directory? If not, try the following:

`adb push C:\the\directory\.`